# XPath does not selects the node that should

Tags: xpath

I want to get GBP over USD exchange rate value from XML.

Code is like this

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument path = new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument(url);
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator nav = path.CreateNavigator();
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator itr = nav.Select("/Envelope/Cube/Cube");
```

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Envelope xmlns="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01">

  <Cube xmlns="http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/iadb/agg_series" SCODE="XUDLUSS" DESC="Spot exchange rate, US $ into Sterling" COUNTRY="" CONCAT="Not seasonally adjusted # Exchange rates # US dollar # Exchange rate (spot) - US dollar into sterling # US dollar ">
    <Cube TIME="2013-07-22" OBS_VALUE="1.537" OBS_CONF="N" LAST_UPDATED="2013-07-23 09:30:00">
    </Cube>
    <Cube TIME="2013-07-23" OBS_VALUE="1.5367" OBS_CONF="N" LAST_UPDATED="2013-07-24 09:30:00">
    </Cube>
  </Cube>
</Envelope>
```

Comment: That looks good so far. What does it return?

Comment: Most likely you need to add the namespaces with an prefix and use this.

Comment: It does not returns anything. I am retrieve this XML from Bank of England and I can't change it. I can change XPath expression. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you need to add the namespaces with an prefix and use this prefixes with your xpath.
Have a look to: [XPathNavigator.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6k4x060d.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)

And try something like this (not tested).

```
System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument path = new System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument(url);
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator nav = path.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
manager.AddNamespace("e", "http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01"");
manager.AddNamespace("c", "http://www.bankofengland.co.uk/boeapps/iadb/agg_series"); 
System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator itr = nav.Select("/e:Envelope/c:Cube/c:Cube", manager );
```